# iPhone Fixed-Position UITableView Background

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background

I'm building an iPhone app without the use of Interface Builder. I have set the background of a grouped UITableView in the following manor:

`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"groupedBackground.png"]];`

I'm trying to fix this background image so that it doesn't scroll with the table cells. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What's your issue with Interface Builder?

Comment: I messed around with it for awhile, but found what I wanted to do was easier to just write it in code. I'm not opposed to using it in the future.

Answer (score 45):

We find that it works exactly as you ask, if instead of using backgroundColor, you assign to backgroundView, like so:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

The table cells then scroll on top of the background, which is stationary.  (This has been available since version 3.2 of the SDK, I believe.)

Comment: Confirmed working in iOS 5.1. This answer should get accepted IMHO, being a more widely applicable solution than the all-too-often advertised method of adding a subview behind the table view (which only works properly if you're not using a UITableViewController).

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve a stationary background using a pattern image as follows:

```
UIView *patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tableView.frame];
patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"groupedBackground.png"]];
patternView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
tableView.backgroundView = patternView;
```

Answer (score 5):

A little late but maybe for all the others looking for a solution. I could get that work by calling the `parentViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `UITableViewController`:

```
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

or with using just a background color:

```
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

It took me a while to figure that out but now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can place an additional view below UITableView and set its background, so if UITableView is transparent - you'll achieve your goal - it will have correct background and it will not scroll.

Comment: This means alpha-blending the UITableView. Have you noticed any performance degradation using this method?

Comment: I used it on a very simple case and therefore haven't seen any degradation. So the only way to know it is to try it, it shouldn't take much time.

Comment: Hmmm... it sounds good, but I'm still having some issues with it. I placed the following code in the ViewDidLoad of my UITableViewController:

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"groupedBackground.png"]];
[self.view addSubview: background];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack: background];

Since "background" is still within the tableView, it scrolls with the rest of it, and the cells are not showing up on top of the background image.

Comment: You can create a simple UIViewController and place background + table to the main view.

Comment: Just to be clear, this does not work with a `UITableViewController`, since in `UITableViewController` `self.view == self.tableView`.  It works if you add a `UITableView` to a `UIViewController`, however

Answer (score 0):

use this below code in swift 3.0 to achieve constant background for tableview

```
 self.tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
```