# Make TableView background not scrollable

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, background, cell

today I've an other problem: I add a background image to a table view and I like that stay stationary when the cells scroll. I found this

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

here [iPhone Fixed-Position UITableView Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960603/iphone-fixed-position-uitableview-background).

but I'm not able to "translate" from Objective-c to Swift... so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
var view = UIImageView(frame: /*whatever you want your frame to be*/)

view.image = //whatever you want your image to be

tableView.backgroundView = view
```